# Parsing a list of lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to `Prolog`. Consider the following example:

```
MainList =  [["A","a","0"],["A","b","0"],["B","a","0"],["B","b","0"],["A","a","1"],["B","b","1"],["C","c","1"],["C","a","0"]]
SubList = ["A","b","-']
```

The format of `MainList`: in the first index it should be the big letter, second index should be small letter and third index should be number. `MainList` can contain other formats (and lengths) but I choose this format because it is easier to explain. I just want to explain that there index of each sublists are divided into categories - first element of each list belongs to `category1`, second element to `category2` and so on. The `"-"` symbol means we does know about the bond of that element with the other elements.

The relation I would like to create should go through the `MainList` and remove all of the sublists that does not follow `SubList`. For the example above, it should return:

```
Output =  [["A","b","0"],["B","a","0"],["C","c","1"],["C","a","0"]]
```

Explanation: `"A"` is working together with `"b"` so every sublists that contains one of those elements, should be checked. if they both exists then it's ok (without duplicates). Otherwise if only one of them exists, it is not ok and we should not insert it into the `Output` list.

Another example (`MainList` is a bit different than the one before):

```
MainList =  [["A","a","0"],["A","b","0"],["B","a","0"],["B","b","0"],["A","b","1"],["B","b","1"],["C","c","1"],["C","a","0"]]
SubList = ["C","a","0"]
Output = [["A","b","1"],["B","b","1"],["C","a","0"]]
```

I do understand the algorithm - we should go through each sublist of the `MainList` and check if the connection of the input-sublist is working, if so, we will insert it into the `Output` list. The problem is, I don't understand how to implement it right. What if the sublist contains more than `2` connections (as was shown in the second example)? How should I treat differently to the sublist?

**EDIT:** I'll try to explain a bit more. The place of each element is important. Each place represents a different category. For example, the first place might represent the big letters, the second place represents the small letters and the third place represents numbers (there could be more categories).
We get a `sublist` which represents a bond between two or more elements. For example we have a bond between `"A"` and `"b"`: `["A","b","-"]`. We should iterate through the sublists of `MainList` and check if each one of those sublists contains one of those elements (`"A"` and `"b"`). If it does, we should check if the bond is correct. For example if we have a sublist that has `A` (in the first index of course), then we should go to the second index and check if `"b"` is there. if it is not there, we should not insert it into the `Output` list, Otherwise we will insert. For example we have a bond `["A","b","-"]` and we got into a sublists of `MainList` which looks as following: `["A","a","0"]` or `["B","b","2"]`. We will not inert those lists into `Output`. But if we got to sublists like: `["A","b","1"]` and `["A","b","2"]` and `["B","a","1"]` we will insert those lists into `Output`.

Comment: *...remove all of the sublists that does not follow `SubList`*. I'm not clear on what this means. In your first example, `["B","a","0"]` follows `["A","b","0"]` which matches the `Sublist`, `["A","b",_]`. In your second example, the output does not include `["A","a","0"]` which does not follow the sublist, `["C","a","0"]`.

Comment: @lurker Thanks for the reply. By follow I meant that there if the sublists is `["A","b","-"]` then we have a bond between `A` and `b`. `["B","a","0"]` does not contain `A` or `b` then we will insert it into `Output`. But `["A","a","0"]` contains `A` but not `b`, so this bond does not true. I'll try to edit it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Also be careful with `_`. It's not at all the same as `"-"`. `_` is an anonymous variable in Prolog. It will unify successfully with any term.

Comment: @lurker Yes, you are right, it is my mistake. Can you see what I'm trying to achieve now? :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a code that satisfies the output conditions for the examples you have given, but did not try other cases or consider the efficiency of the code, so you can maybe improve upon it. Here is the code :

```
subList(List,SubL,Out):-
    (member("-",SubL),
     select("-",SubL,SubRem)
    ;
    \+ member("-",SubL),
    SubRem = SubL),
    findall(L,((member(L,List),checkEq(SubRem,L));
           (member(L,List),checkNeq(SubRem,L))),Out).

checkEq([],_).
checkEq([S|Rest],[E|List]):-
    S == E,
    checkEq(Rest,List).

checkNeq([],_).
checkNeq([S|Rest],List) :-
    \+ member(S,List),
    checkNeq(Rest,List).
```

Explanation: What I did is that, first I removed the "-" character from the subarray(if it exists) in order to make the computations easier. Then, I either check the condition that each element in the **SubList** is in order with the elements of the selected *sublist* of the **MainList**. If this fails, I then check if none of the elements of **SubList** is contained in the selected sublist. If both checks fail, I move to the next sublist. Using findall/3 predicate, I find all combinations that satisfy either of these conditions and group them in the list *Out*

EDIT: Add the additional clause for the `checkEq` predicate :

```
checkEq([S|Rest],[E|List]):-
    S \= E,
    member(S,List),
    checkEq([S|Rest],List).
```

So the final version is :

```
checkEq([],_).
checkEq([S|Rest],[E|List]):-
    S == E,
    checkEq(Rest,List).

checkEq([S|Rest],[E|List]):-
    S \= E,
    member(S,List),
    checkEq([S|Rest],List).
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was trying to test the code with the following example: `subList([["A","a","0","~"],["A","b","0","~"],["B","a","0","%"],["B","b","0","~"],["A","b","1","^"],["B","b","1","%"],["C","c","1","~"],["C","a","0","+"]],["A","b","-","~"],Out).` (I added another category - operators). But the output is `[["B", "a", "0", "%"], ["C", "a", "0", "+"]]` But it should be `[["A","b","0","~"],["B","a","0","%"],["C","a","0","+"]]`. How to change it?

Comment: It works if `"-"` is at the end, but from the OP example I understand that it isnt always the case. It won't work for `subList([["A","a","1"],["B","a","0"]],["A","-","1"],Out)`.

Comment: Okay, got the idea about that. Can you add the additional term to the `checkEq` in my edit and try it again please ?

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal works great! I'm trying to create a similar function which will remove the bonds (does the opposite of your function). for example: `mainList` is `[["A","a","0"],["B",'b","0"]]` and sublist is `["A","-","0"]` then the output should be "["B","b',"0"]` because `"A"` and `"0"` can't be together in same sublist. I was trying to switch between the `checkEq` and `checkNeq` algorithms, but without any success. What can I do?

Comment: Well `checkNeq` checks if none of the elements in the SubList is in our selected list. So in this case you can simply revert the clause `\+ member()` to just `member()`in that predicate. In that case, it will return true if all the elements in SubList are also members of the selected list. Then, you can find all lists for which this predicate returns false.

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal I removed the `\+` operator but it returns duplicates. What do you mean by "find all lists for which this predicate returns false"? Should I change also `checkEq`?

Comment: By find all lists, I meant to modify the `findall` command. In the `subList` method, change the last line to this :`findall(L,((member(L,List),\+ checkNeq(SubRem,L))),Out).` If you changed the `checkNeq` as I suggested, it should work.

Comment: I get it. Can you tell me why the following test does not work: `subList([[table, dogs, red, football], [table, dogs, red, basketball], [table, dogs, blue, football]],[table,blue,"-","-'],Out).` It returns `[]` but it should return `[table, dogs, blue, football]`. Is it because the `subList` is not in the same indexes as the `MainList`. If so, how can I solve it?

Comment: Well, since this comment section is becoming too long, I'll stop writing the comments, but you can find the basic operations you need for the code to work properly from this point on. For the case you've written, what you need to do that you make sure you have deleted all "-" characters from the `SubList` . Right now, the predicate I wrote works for the case that there is only 1 "-" character in the `SubList`. You can modify it slightly to remove all "-" characters, and then it should work. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187246/discussion-between-vesii-and-koralp-catalsakal).